# Problem with R impish repo in Ubuntu 22.04 - impish-cran40

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, apt, cran

Following the install instructions:

```
wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu impish-cran40/"
sudo update
```

Then get errors:

```
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu impish-cran40/ InRelease' provides only weak security information.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Never had such a problem on Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to figure out what exactly caused the error message, without success.  However, a proper fix is available now that the CRAN maintainers have added a jammy (22.04) repository.

This should upgrade you to the jammy repository:

```
sudo sed -i -e s/impish/jammy/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list
```

Alternatively, using `add-apt-repository`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu impish-cran40/"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/"
```

Comment: Perfect, works great!

Comment: Using this solution really worked, but I had a problem with libc6. My solution was setting the repository to focal-cran40: deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/, even though I'm using ubuntu 21.10 (impish).

Comment: The second suggestion worked for me. I added a repository for kinetic-kudu that is at present empty. Now removed, thank you!